# Simple code to install a subversion repository on a linux server

Tags: svn

What is the simplest way to install a private subversion repository on a Linux server - specifically a bluehost shared server?

Apache version 2.2.13 (Unix)

PHP version 5.2.9

Architecture x86_64

Operating system Linux

Commands welcome....

I saw the code on this site - http://www.bluehosttricks.com/2009/07/18/bluehost-installing-svn/ - but it seems like a lot of extra... can someone simplify and explain this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a great solution at http://www.bluehostforum.com/showthread.php?s=855d68319128c0db09b4d88e844287c0&t=12099&page=3
except the most recent version right now is 1.6.5

This is much better than the last link I posted as the dependencies are taken into account by the 4th line

```
mkdir src
cd src
wget http://subversion.tigris.org/downloads/subversion-1.6.5.tar.bz2
wget http://subversion.tigris.org/downloads/subversion-deps-1.6.5.tar.bz2
tar -xvjpf  subversion-1.6.5.tar.bz2
tar -xvjpf  subversion-deps-1.6.5.tar.bz2
cd subversion-1.6.5
./configure --prefix=$HOME --without-berkeley-db --with-ssl LDFLAGS="-L/lib64"
make
make install
```

Comment: You neglected to update the version of Subversion from 1.6.4 to 1.6.5 in a couple of places.

Answer (score 2):

Since you mention it is a 'shared' server you probably don't have the ability to install the subversion binary if it isn't already present, or the ability to enable the SVN apache modules.

It may not be possible to setup a subversion server.

Comment: Even if you can't install the apache modules, you can always download the source, compile it in your home dir, and use it over ssh.

Comment: @Cian, My experience is that in tightly locked down shared environments you aren't provided with a compiler.  I haven't used bluehost though.  I was just offering some a guess based on other shared hosts I have used.

Comment: I do have SSH access - I am looking for the commands to compile it and setup a project